# How do you install a GUI like GNOME on a Linux machine via PuTTY?

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop

1. I installed PuTTY on my Windows machine
2. I've been able to do remote login to my Linux machine (it is not local) via PuTTY command prompt

With that in mind, how do I install a GUI like GNOME and then log into it remotely?

Answer (score 3):

Are you wanting to view the entire desktop remotely? That would require something like VNC.

If you are just wanting to view one application that has a GUI, you will need to install something like [xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) and enable X forwarding.

Both of these, especially the VNC resuires a very large amount of bandwidth, and I wouldn't recommend it over the internet unless both machines have very fast connections.

If you are just wanting to install these, you can use the package manager, but that only enables you to log in at that machine, not remotely.

Answer (score 0):

At Fedora, you can run this to install Gnome DE:

```
yum groupinstalll "GNOME Desktop Environment"
```

If you were running Ubuntu, then you could install gnome desktop with this:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Then you can use `vinagre` and `vino-preferences` to configure the remote access.